# Can stunned aliens recover?

Tags: xenonauts

When stunning an alien is it necessary to keep an eye on them, to make sure they don't get up again? Or does an alien remain unconscious once they have passed out?

Comment: In the original X-COM they would wake up again, but would wander around without their weapons, which they left on the ground. So I would expect that the aliens would recover, although who's to say what their combat effectiveness would be after being knocked out.

Comment: Did not happen in any of my missions. And I stun them quite often.
Not in 10 turns, I would say.

Comment: @maxywb that's why i'd carry them in my backpack in the original in case they did wake up so I wouldn't have to go searching for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once knocked out, they aren't getting back up. This includes friendly or hostile AI, as well as your own troops. They can be damaged, but will stop bleeding. By this I mean don't toss frags at them.